# playframework and mysql - how to pass connection properties?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, playframework, connection, playframework-2.0

from application.conf:

```
db.default.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&more Conn Properties
```

I'm coming from java/spring/wicket to scala/play and I just can't stand to see this kind of connection parameter passing.

With java/spring I could encapsulate the connection properties in some bean and then reference it by the datasource bean. The props would then be passed on to the jdbc driver. So the url would be clean and the conn props were defined also "cleanly".

Anyway to achieve this with scala/play? through application.conf? through global.scala perhaps? anything except putting my conn props in the url directly??